# C# thread abort exception

Tags: c#, multithreading

**What happens after a thread.Abort() ??**

Say i have:

```
Thread mWorker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.run));
..
mWorker.Start();

**where**

private void run() 
{
      Logger.d(TAG, "run()");

      ...
      try {
        while (this.mRunning){
          ...
        }
      } catch (ThreadAbortException tae){
           Logger.e(TAG,"some msg", tae);
           this.doSomething();
      } catch (IOException ioe){
           Logger.e(TAG,"some msg", ioe);
           this.doSomething();
      } catch (Exception e){
           Logger.e(TAG,"some msg", e);
           this.doSomething();
      } finally {
            gracefoulyClose();
      }

      Logger.d(TAG, "run() - ended");
}
```

Thread is more complex.. but the esential is displayed here. So what happens when Abort() gets called? will my catch work and continue with the call of doSomething()?

Because i still receive in console:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

But i do have a catch for that. Don't I ??

Answer (score 7):

From the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx):

> When a call is made to the Abort method to destroy a thread, the
>   common language runtime throws a ThreadAbortException.
>   **ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it
>   will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block**. When
>   this exception is raised, **the runtime executes all the finally blocks
>   before ending the thread**. Because the thread can do an unbounded
>   computation in the finally blocks or call Thread.ResetAbort to cancel
>   the abort, there is no guarantee that the thread will ever end. If you
>   want to wait until the aborted thread has ended, you can call the
>   Thread.Join method. Join is a blocking call that does not return until
>   the thread actually stops executing.

So in other words, after your catch block for the `ThreadAbortException` executes, the exception is re-raised, so your last logger line (e.g. `Logger.d(TAG, "run() - ended")`)  never executes. But since the call to `this.doSoemthing` is in the catch block for the `ThreadAbortException`, it **will** execute.

Note also that, your `finally` block **does** execute (refer to doc above).

Comment: so is my try catch OK? because when u use a "try {code A} catch (Ex e){}" .. you know that code A might trow a exception.. but my code doesnt throw thread Abort.. Dont know if i am making sens? is my code going to catch a AbortExcetion?

Comment: If something in your while loop causes a ThreadAbortException, then yes, it will be caught in your catch block. ThreadAbortException is a special exception that might be thrown by the .Net runtime, not necessarily your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some where in code  `response.redirect();` then it will internally
run `thread.abort();`  so it will throw exception.Instead of that you can use    `Response.Redirect(url,false);`

Comment: I'm getting `thread abort exception` when I use the `Response.End();`, but if I use `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` instead I don't get the exception but a new exception `Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent` occurs,any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a ThreadAbortException because your context is exiting before the thread is finished running. You need to wait on the thread to complete before you exit. If you want to exit, you need to make sure that your thread can receive a signal (and act upon it) that your program wishes to end, and then your code that manages program execution must wait on the thread to complete:

```
if (mThread != null && mThread.IsAlive) {
    mThread.Join();
}
```

Use the overload with the timeout if you're worried about the thread never exiting, and kill the thread explicitly if you hit the timer.

Comment: You check mThread != null && mThread.IsAlive in one line. That can cause access violation if the mThread is null.

Comment: As long as the null check is the first item in the conditional, no error would be thrown. This is merely an example, and is not meant to fit all circumstances of software. Focus less on the pedantic, and more on the question at hand.